# How to fix 500 Internal Server Error for POST integration tests using TestServer and Antiforgery? ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-core, integration-testing, internal-server-error

I've got a working ASP.NET Core 2.2 implementation that utilizes both MVC and API controllers, and I'm putting together an integration test project to cover everything that has already been tested manually - the basic crud, mostly. Everything works except the tests that use PostAsync to POST data. These tests always get a 500 Internal Server Error as a response from the client, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. Oi!

The TestServer setup is a pretty standard approach that I've seen on many different blogs and articles. A TestStartup class extends the standard Startup, and overrides the configuration to use in-memory database with seed data. My test fixture base then uses the TestStartup to create a server, and a client, and has a method, which I know works fine, to extract the antiforgery token and add it to forms and headers. All other tests verifying all other aspects of CRUD are working, proving that the seeded data can be retrieved, via both MVC and API calls.

The POST calls that eventually fail with a 500 Internal Server Error do make it into the controller, and the subsequent repository, just fine. With all these aspects in place, I've yet to be able to see the source of the 500.

```
    [Fact]
    public async void CreatePost_ShouldReturnViewWithNewlyCreatedLabelData()
    {
        // Arrange
        var formData = await EnsureAntiForgeryTokenOnForm(new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "Name", TestDataGraph.Labels.LabelNew.Name },
            { "WebsiteUrl", TestDataGraph.Labels.LabelNew.WebsiteUrl }
        });

        // Act
        var response = await Client.PostAsync("/labels/create", new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData));

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.Found, response.StatusCode);
        Assert.Equal("/Labels", response.Headers.Location.ToString());
    }
```

This is a simple example test in Xunit that attempts to validate the creation of a new simple object, type Label, via MVC route, which follows the standard path format, having been scaffolded. This test will make it into the controller, and its repository, but the response will be a 500 Internal Server Error.

Could I have missed something important in Startup? Any ideas for finding further details about this failure? Thanks in advance! I can post more code or details if they will be helpful.

Comment: _"I cannot for the life of me figure out why."_ So the body (once you've added the developer exception page) doesn't give you any clues? Normally it gives an exception and a stack trace...

Comment: @John As it is an integration test, there's no page to inspect that I'm aware of. I'm trying to find a way to log these details from my integration test project. If I try to do this through the app (add a new Label), it will work just fine.

Comment: `var responsePage = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`? - Remember that a "page" is just HTML data served over an HTTP connection.

Comment: @John Yes - apologies, I was under the impression the page wasn't getting used with this TestStartup, but as it inherits from the og Startup, it indeed does, and I'm now inspecting it from the response. It looks like the root issue is a duplicate key problem, which is surprising, so I need to clean that up. Thanks for kickstarting my brain on that front, though!

Comment: No worries :) By the way, the developer exception page is just middleware (see the code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/082d505977d72c75b68935c93c21feded6928e5f/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics/DeveloperExceptionPage/DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.cs)). If you wanted a more machine-readable exception response, you could write your own to serialize the `Exception` object to JSON, for example.

Comment: @John Oh absolutely. I realize my question looks a little noobish now, as I stumble over some aspects of ASP.NET Core, but it's nice to see that otb middleware work so easily for the test server. My issue here is actually that the test server uses 1 as the Id, which is a dup and fails (seed data). Unexpected, as I'm leaving the Id off, but the test server is unaware of the seed data. Test will pass if I force in an Id, but that doesn't match its real world usage. Might I have left off a config setting to ensure that the test server knows which Id to assign next? Cheers

Comment: What is the id used for? Is it to identify a label?

Comment: @John yes, just the primary key Id value on a poco domain entity

Comment: Can you provide some code for where that issue is happening? I'm not sure if I can help, but it might help understand the issue. If it's Entity Framework, I probably can't help - I have no experience there, I'm afraid. Hopefully someone else can :)

Comment: Yeah man, no worries. It's EF, and I'm just trying to mock the same behavior as the scaffolded MVC controller (and API controller, for that matter) that accept new data without the Id, and end up passing a 0 to EF's dataContext in this situation. That fails my test too. At this point, I should probably just write a new question about that if it remains a bugger. But you've been more than helpful in helping me get my stack trace in order for this test server, so thanks a bunch!

Comment: @AR9 sorry to necro this question - were you getting 500 errors locally or on a CI server? I have my GET requests working locally but they fail on a CI server, I don't have any DB dependencies so I can discount that.

Comment: @MattStannett No worries. This was local development. If I remember correctly, there were actually a couple of different 500 errors I was encountering getting this set up, and they were surrounding domain types that were part of table-per-inheritance, and thusly, had some intricacies that needed to be handled (particularly for updates). These were integration tests and I believe the errors were coming from InMemoryDb. Sounds like your case is different as it's with GET, and without any db. Can you give more detail on the 500 you're seeing? Able to debug it for the details?

Comment: @AR9 I actually went back through the stacktrace and found that there is a null ref exception buried in there to do with the OpenIdConnectOptionsConfiguration. I have a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213911/asp-net-core-integration-test-works-locally-but-throws-null-reference-exception.

Comment: An MVC controller will normally have a **[ValidateAntiForgeryToken] ** attribute on the create post.  Try temporarily removing the attribute to see if that is your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding trace logging...  Trace logging will display activity in the .Net Core framework.

```
...
public static ILogger<ConsoleLoggerProvider> AppLogger = null;
public static ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = null;
//
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLogging(builder => builder
        .AddConsole()
        .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Trace)
    );
    loggerFactory = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
    AppLogger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ConsoleLoggerProvider>();
    ...
```

An example trace log:

```
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorViewCompiler[7]
    Could not find a file for view at path '/Views/Home/_Layout.cshtml'.
```

After you have resolved the issue, change the LogLevel to a more appropriate value.